# ASP.NET MVC - What's the best way to create a Url to controller action from within view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to figure out the best way to create a url to a controller action from within a view. The problem I am running into is when I deploy the application to different machines with and without a virtual application root the url changes slightly.

So I want to be able to construct the url dynamically and the method needs to be aware of whether or not the application is running in an application root or if it resides at the root.

So what helpers/classes should I be leveraging to get this done?

```
<%=ResolveUrl(string.Concat(Request.Url.Authority,Request.ApplicationPath) + "/Session/GetSessionFile/" + Model.SessionID + "/" + Model.FileName)%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Url.Action()` helper:

```
<%=Url.Action("GetSessionFile", "Session") + '/'  Model.SessionID + '/' + Model.FileName %>
```

UPDATE:

I'll try to guess your routing configuration. If it contains the following statement:

```
routes.MapRoute("Session_Route", "{controller}/{action}/{sessionId}/{arg}");
```

you surely should pass the parameters that way:

```
<%=Url.Action("GetSessionFile", "Session", new { sessionId = Model.SessionID, arg = Model.FileName}) %>
```

Comment: @Nick, I think a more elegant solution exists. I need to see the routes configuration from the Global.asax to get it.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `Url.Action`.  You pass the action as one of the paramters.  Then a series of route values for the others.  I'm guessing what those route value keys are (`id` and `fileName`):

```
<%= Url.Action("GetSessionFile", new { id = Model.SessionId, fileName = Model.FileName })
```

Comment: +1 This is really the way this should be done.  The 'selected' answer is hardcoding a route vs using route definitions.

Comment: @Justin Soliz, I didn't have intent to hardcode anything, I just don't know what is in the routes collection.

Comment: @bniwrdyc Totally understand where you're coming from. At the same time, the worst case scenario is you get a url with visible query string parameters '/contoller/action?sessionId=1&fileName=something' but it'll still hit the controller method and you can change route definitions accordingly.  Thanks for the response, +1 coming your way.